gRPC in container is not working - and yes, I am exposing and enabling the needed ports
I have a .Net API program named "myservice" that provides an API via gRPC on port 5053 and a video stream via RTSP on port 8554.
When I run the program from the command line with 'dotnet myservice.dll', it works properly. A client can access the gRPC API on port 5053 and VLC can play the video stream on port 8554.
I also created a VS Code devcontainer for this program. The devcontainer uses a custom Dockerfile and there is no configuration in the devcontainer.json file.
The program also works properly when run in VS Code (debug start) from the devcontainer.
If I exit VS code and build the container using the same Dockerfile, when I run the conainer the gRPC API does not work, but VLC can still play the video stream on port 8554.
The symptom is that the client gests an exception ""Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake".
The command line I use to start the container is:
docker run -p 8554:8554 -p 5053:5053 -p 5054:5054 -it --rm myservice

The Dockerfile does contain a command to start the service, and when I start the container interactively, I see the normal debug output from the service with no errors indicated.
I am doing this on Windows 10 Pro. The client and the service are both on .Net 8.0. Docker is latest version.
How can I troubleshoot this problem?
Running the container:
docker run -p 8554:8554 -p 5053:5053 -it --rm myservice:1.0

(Normal output from the service is seen)
Running the test client:
myclient.exe
Expect to see "Connect successful". Instead see
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An HTTP/2 connection could not be established because the server did not complete the HTTP/2 handshake.")
As I said, in this case VLC still plays the video stream on port 8554. This stream is generated by the service (I call a native DLL that uses gstreamer to do this.)

Does the server listen to 127.0.0.1 only?

No, it is targeted at 0.0.0.0

Well, that was apparently not the case.
Changing the address in appsettings.json from localhost fixed it.
Not sure why, though. All running on same host. Result of Docker's networking implementation?
